# QGiS 3.0: Line length without overlapping parts

Tags: qgis, line, overlapping-features, length

I have overlapping lines in my layer and want a total length of the visible line without the overlapping part.

i.e.

I have two lines

First one goes A-B-C

Second one is B-C-D

How do I get the length from A-B-C-D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the lines overlap exactly on top of each other then I would suggest dissolving them or merging them into a single line in a separate layer and getting the length of that line using the $length function in the field calculator.